# NPE in Ignite 2.9 SpringCacheManager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ignite, spring-cache

We are catching NPE in SpringCacheManager during application startup:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager.getCache(SpringCacheManager.java:357)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver.resolveCaches(AbstractCacheResolver.java:89)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:253)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:724)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:266)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContexts.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:615)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:346)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
```

It seems that spring boot application started early than cache manager is becoming ready to work.
If we look into ignite code:

```
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override public Cache getCache(String name) {
    assert ignite != null;

    SpringCache cache = caches.get(name);

    if (cache == null) {
        CacheConfiguration<Object, Object> cacheCfg = dynamicCacheCfg != null ?
            new CacheConfiguration<>(dynamicCacheCfg) : new CacheConfiguration<>();

        NearCacheConfiguration<Object, Object> nearCacheCfg = dynamicNearCacheCfg != null ?
            new NearCacheConfiguration<>(dynamicNearCacheCfg) : null;

        cacheCfg.setName(name);

        cache = new SpringCache(nearCacheCfg != null ? ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg, nearCacheCfg) :
            ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg), this); // (SpringCacheManager.java:357)

        SpringCache old = caches.putIfAbsent(name, cache);

        if (old != null)
            cache = old;
    }

    return cache;
}
```

I have no idea of NPE reasons, and how to avoid it.

We are using: Ignite 2.9, spring cache.

Could you help?)

Comment: Could you please share how you configure Ignite? The only possible reason for this error is `ignite` field of the manger being `null`.

Comment: We solved this issue with using spring boot actuator readiness. If this error occurs just set readiness to false. It helps to avoid of getting requests from other services before SpringCahceManager will be ready to work.